# Retrieve Big data using EF

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, indexing, repository

I have two tables "Kelime"

```
public class Kelime
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Word { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and "Anlam"

```
public class Anlam
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Meaning { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int Kelimesi_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Kelimesi_ID")]
    public virtual Kelime kelime { get; set; }
}
```

Both tables contains more than 80k datas. I don't think they are very big but I am having problem on this query:

```
Repository<Kelime> _rk = new Repository<Kelime>();
Repository<Anlam> _ra = new Repository<Anlam>();

IEnumerable<int> kelimeIdler = _ra.All().Select(s => s.Kelimesi_ID).Distinct();
int _kelimecik= _rk.Find(w => !kelimeIdler.Contains(w.ID)).ID;
```

or `Kelime _kelimecim = _rk.All().Where(w => !kelimeIdler.Contains(w.ID)).FirstOrDefault();`

I am trying to take the "Kelime", "Kelime List" or its "id" it doesn't matter which are not in my "Anlam" table. There is a timeout when it comes to "contains" part. I tried to write non clustered index but it doesn't accept subquery. What should I do to achieve what I want? Thank you very much.

Comment: 80k is not big data. The timeout is raised by SQL Server so the EF is not really the problem. You can see the runned query in SQL server (Profiler) then optimize it adding the right indexes

Comment: thank you for your response sql server profiler doesnt help but as you said ef was not the problem. The problem is based on my "data context" I use "singleton pattern" and my problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static DataContext _context;

public static DataContext ContextOlustur()
{
    if (_context == null)
    {
        _context = new DataContext();
    }

    return _context;
}
```

Adding this pattern to my data context class solved my problem. Because my queries used two different context that's why it was getting problem to connect database and got time out. This pattern prevents creating another context.